# Localized month names in Firebird

Tags: sql, timestamp, firebird

I need to get various parts of a TIMESTAMP field - specifically *year*, *localized month name* (in Russian), *day of month* and *hours interval* (like '11 - 12').

Currently i came up with this:

```sql
select
extract (year from prt.dtbegin) as f_year,
(
  case extract (month from prt.dtbegin)
    when 1 then 'Январь'
    when 2 then 'Февраль'
    /* ... */
    when 12 then 'Декабрь'
  end
) as f_month,
cast (lpad (extract (day from prt.dtbegin), 2, 0) as char(2)) as f_day,
(
  cast (lpad (extract (hour from prt.dtbegin), 2, 0) as char(2)) 
  || ' - '
  || cast (lpad (extract (hour from prt.dtbegin) + 1, 2, 0) as char(2)) 
) as f_hour
from prt
```

It works fine (interval '23 - 24' is OK at the moment), but I don't like it, especially CASE sentence with each and every month.

So, i'd like to know, is there any common way of getting localized month names in Firebird? Also, can i format extracted parts of timestamp, instead of current cast-lpad-extract construct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first question here, don't know where all the code formatting gone, it looks fine in the preview

Comment: I have posted a suggested edit formatting your code. The quickest way of getting the formatting is to select the code and then press the {} button at the top of the question box.

Comment: What's your application programming language? Delphi, C++, Perl? That language likely has a library that does what you're looking for, like [DateTime::Locale](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Locale/) in Perl.

Comment: Surely it has, but i wanted to get these names directly from the query.

Answer (score 0):

What about a reference table with the localised strings in them with a key of the month number. I thought this was done in the Firebird system tables, but have not been able to find documentation or the location in the system tables, if indeed it is there.

EDIT:
I have checked the system tables, and the documentation, and the literals are not available within Firebird itself. Sorry :-)

Comment: Yes, i considered adding a reference table, but i don't want to alter database because of this particular query. I thought there's some sort of built-in feature i don't know about that'll make it look less ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in feature for that. You should consider writing your own UDF for that. Once done, it's very simple to use. The following resources should point you in the right direction:

- [Writing UDFs for InterBase](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/writing-udfs-for-interbase/)
- [How to write UDF's in Delphi?](https://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq83/)
- [How to write an internal UDF function](https://www.ibphoenix.com/articles/art-00000406)

I sure hope next major release (3.0) will support writing internal functions.

**Update**

Firebird 3.0 **will** support internal SQL Functions: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-2047

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CASE` you can use the [`DECODE` builtin function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-conditional.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-decode).